# Store result with preserved type from SQL native function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to simply store a type DATETIME returned by the native mySql function NOW() in a variable in php, such that I can use it in an insert call. I couldn't find a function that can fetch this data without having a 'column' or 'row' from a table to index it. An example of what I'm trying to do is below.

```
$db = ...//successful connection to database
$time = mysqli_query($db, "NOW()");
$attempt = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('$val1', '$val2', $time, '$val3')");
...
```

Comment: Why not just put `NOW()` in the `INSERT` instead of `$time`?

Comment: @Nick I need to use that exact time in a future SQL command

Comment: Then you need a solution such as @Barmar answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just call functions, you need to use a query. And then you have to fetch the results the same way as any other query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT NOW() as now");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$time = $row['now'];
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to index 'now' from mysqli_fetch_assoc